# Can't hide image on collision in libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I just started working with LibGDX and can't figure out how to hide an image when it collides with an object. In my game some dots come from the top of the screen and meet the dot at the bottom. When they meet the dots should hide that isn't happening.

This is the main Game Class

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen,InputProcessor {
   final AmazingDot game;

   //setting the height and width variables
   private int height;
   private int width;
   private static int touchCounter;

   //setting the two dots variables
   private Texture playerDotImage;
   private Texture gameDotImage;
   private Texture gameDotImage1;

   private Rectangle playerDotRectangle;
   private Map<Rectangle,Texture> gameDotMap;

   //storing the time of last dot in nano seconds
   private long lastDotTime;

   public GameScreen(final AmazingDot gam){
       this.game = gam;
       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

       //getting the height and width of the user's screen
       height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
       width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
       touchCounter =0;

       //loading the images in the variables
       playerDotImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/dot2.png"));

       gameDotImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/dot1.png"));
       gameDotImage1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/dot2.png"));

       //placing the player dot in the middle of the screen
       playerDotRectangle = new Rectangle();
       playerDotRectangle.x = width/ 2 - 64 / 2;
       playerDotRectangle.y = 20;
       playerDotRectangle.width = 64;
       playerDotRectangle.height = 64;

       gameDotMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Rectangle, Texture>();

       populateDots();
   }

   private void populateDots(){
       Rectangle dots = new Rectangle();
       dots.x = randomLocation();
       dots.y = height;
       dots.width = 64;
       dots.height = 64;

       Random rand = new Random();
       int  n = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
       if(n==1){
           gameDotMap.put(dots,gameDotImage1);
       }
       else{
           gameDotMap.put(dots,gameDotImage);
       }

       lastDotTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
   }

   private int randomLocation(){
       int[] locations = new int[3];
       locations[0]=0;
       locations[1]=width/2-64/2;
       locations[2]=width-64;

       Random generator = new Random();
       int randomIndex = generator.nextInt(locations.length);
       return locations[randomIndex];
   }

   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       game.batch.begin();

       game.batch.draw(playerDotImage,playerDotRectangle.x,playerDotRectangle.y,playerDotRectangle.width,playerDotRectangle.height);

       for(Map.Entry<Rectangle,Texture> dots : gameDotMap.entrySet()){
           game.batch.draw(dots.getValue(),dots.getKey().x,dots.getKey().y);
       }

       game.batch.end();

       // check if we need to create a new dot
       if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDotTime > 1000000000) populateDots();

       for(Rectangle dot : gameDotMap.keySet()){

           int gameSpeed = 400;
           int xSpeed = calXSpeed(gameSpeed);
           dot.y = dot.y - gameSpeed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

           if(dot.x <width/2-64/2){
               dot.x = dot.x + xSpeed*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
           }
           else if(dot.x>width/2-64/2){
               dot.x = dot.x - xSpeed*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
           }
           if(dot.y + 64 < 0) gameDotMap.remove(dot);
           if(dot.overlaps(playerDotRectangle)) {
               //this is where I am trying to remove the map object on collision
               gameDotMap.remove(dot);
           }
       }
   }

   private int calXSpeed(int gameSpeed){
       int seconds = height/gameSpeed;
       int distance = width/2-64/2;
       int speed = distance/seconds;
       return speed;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
       touchCounter++;
       if(touchCounter % 2==0){
           playerDotImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/dot2.png"));
       }
       else{
           playerDotImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/dot1.png"));
       }
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
       playerDotImage.dispose();
       gameDotImage.dispose();
       gameDotImage1.dispose();
   }
}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

As you can see in the above image when the moving dot reaches the stationary dot, it should disappear. But here in my code the dot just moves past the stationary dot. I am using rectangles(LibGdx) to detect whether the dots overlap each other or not.

Comment: Want is actually happening now? The dots don't collide at all and continue? Or do they stop at the collision point? More details please :)

Comment: There is a stationary dot at the bottom center of the screen, I am detecting when the dot coming from the top overlaps the stationary dot. If it does I am removing that dot from the map.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused - what is going wrong? You say that you are removing the dot, which sounds like everything you need is working!? In your original question, what is this image you need to hide!?

Comment: I am Sorry I messed up in explaining what exactly was wrong. I have edited the question. You might understand it better now.

Comment: Does the collision actually occur? Have you tried placing a `Gdx.app.log(...)` inside the if statement to see if it is really hitting?

Comment: Yes I tried it, My log message is getting displayed, which means it is entering the if statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define you `Map` as an [ArrayMap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ArrayMap.html) like so:

```
private ArrayMap<Rectangle, Texture> gameDotMap;
```

Then you can rewrite you `render` method like this:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    game.batch.begin();

    game.batch.draw(playerDotImage, playerDotRectangle.x, playerDotRectangle.y, playerDotRectangle.width, playerDotRectangle.height);

    for (int i = 0; i < gameDotMap.size; i++) {
        game.batch.draw(gameDotMap.getValueAt(i), gameDotMap.getKeyAt(i).x, gameDotMap.getKeyAt(i).y);
    }

    game.batch.end();

    // check if we need to create a new dot
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDotTime > 1000000000) {
        populateDots();
    }

    for (Iterator<ObjectMap.Entry<Rectangle, Texture>> iter = gameDotMap.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        ObjectMap.Entry<Rectangle, Texture> entry = iter.next();
        Rectangle dot = entry.key;
        int gameSpeed = 400;
        int xSpeed = calXSpeed(gameSpeed);
        dot.y = dot.y - gameSpeed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        if (dot.x < width / 2 - 64 / 2) {
            dot.x = dot.x + xSpeed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        } else if (dot.x > width / 2 - 64 / 2) {
            dot.x = dot.x - xSpeed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        }
        if (dot.y + 64 < 0) {
            iter.remove();
        }
        if (dot.overlaps(playerDotRectangle)) {
            //this is where I am trying to remove the map object on collision
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

LibGDX has specific types for collections, they are recommended over the JDK's collections.

Comment: Hey, thank you very much it worked. Btw why can't I use Java collections?

Comment: The main reason for using LibGDX collections is performance. With the ConcurrentHashMap though it would seem the removal does not occur when it should in your code and next call to render keeps the reference to the removed dot, hence the funny effect you got.